# Function components forwardRef syntax

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref

I wrote all my code using componets like this.

```
export default myFunc(props){
    return <input placeholder={props.placeholder} />;
}
```

For consistency reasons I want to keep using this kind of syntax for the other components while using forwardRef, but I can only find examples like this;

```
export const myFunc = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
 <input ref={ref} placeholder={props.placeholder} />
});
```

Is there any way to use forwardRef using same syntax as the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is the only way to pass ref to children as described in [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

> *Note The second ref argument only exists when you define a component with React.forwardRef call. Regular function or class components don’t
> receive the ref argument, and ref is not available in props either.
> Ref forwarding is not limited to DOM components. You can forward refs
> to class component instances, too.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and in fact I would recommend using this syntax:

```js
export default forwardRef(function MyFunc(props, ref)
{
    return <input ref={ref} placeholder={props.placeholder} />;
})
```

---

The example you provided actually has a big downside:

```js
export const MyFunc = forwardRef((props, ref) =>
{
    return <input ref={ref} placeholder={props.placeholder} />
});
```

In your example you used an anonymous function, which would make your code hard to debug if you tried to look at component names.

Instead it is best to always use named functions:

```js
export const MyFunc = forwardRef(function MyFunc(props, ref)
{
    return <input ref={ref} placeholder={props.placeholder} />
});
```

Notice that I used the same name for the function and for the const variable.
This way you can not accidentally use the wrong name.

---

And I noticed you were using a lowercase name for your components: `myFunc`.
Component names should always start with an uppercase letter: `MyFunc`.